# how to Show loading box while sending data?

Tags: android, dialog, thread-sleep

Hi everyone i am facing problem in showing loading box on pressing send button using send_Schedule() function. I have the following code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
pdialog.setCancelable(true);
pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
pdialog.show();
send_Schedule();
```

}

In send_Schedule() function i am putting delay of 3 secs like this in the following code. but dialog box always shows up after completion of loop.

```
send_Schedule(){
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       Log.d("TAG",""+i)
       try {
     Thread.sleep(3000);
      Log.e("----------------", "-----------------");
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   pdialog.dismiss();
 }
```

I want to show dialog box while sending data...

Comment: u can use asynctask for that...

Comment: Is there any exception ? You should also dismiss the dialog in case of exception.

Comment: @keshav no there are no exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 private class YourTaskLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Importing Messages...!");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Write you back ground logic here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Invoke like in your Activity

```
new YourTaskLoader().execute();
```

Check this more info [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)